# Modeling and updating the reliability of two sources of information

Tags: logistic, bayesian, decision-theory, choice-modeling

I do not know the general framework this might fall under, apologies for the vague title.

Assume that a decision maker's choice is dependent on two sources of information $f_1$ and $f_2$. Assume for simplicity the decision is a weighted linear model of the two $y = w_1 f_1 + w_2 f_2$.
for example, imagine there are 2 boxes, and $f_1 = \{3,10\}$ and $f_2=\{10, 6\}$ denote the expected reward in each box according to each of the information sources. In this setting, $w_i$ represents the degree to which we believe each source. The observed utility $u_i$ of choosing box $i$ is the reward in it, but the decision as to choose which one is based on the perceived utility. The choice itself follows a logit function $p(i) = \frac{exp(u_i)}{\sum(exp(u_i)}$, where the utility $u_i$ is a function of $y$.

Upon choosing one of the boxes, the realized reward is $u'_i$. Based on this, the decision maker wants to update its belief in the sources of information, i.e., $w_1$ and $w_2$.

To me, this seems like a multinomial logistic regression except the true value is not a discrete label, rather a real-valued number. 
How would one go about modeling this? Any hints as to keywords to search for and topics to read would be appreciated.